# blocking css resources. this causes a delay in rendering your page

Tags: html, css

Im getting this error when running page speed insights: blocking css resources. this causes a delay in rendering your page

However, how can I do this differently? The CSS in minified, and I cant really place the CSS in the footer, so I dont get why im complains about this?

The page im having this problem is waves-shopping.dk

And the insights:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=www.waves-shopping.dk&tab=desktop

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As both CSS and JavaScript might affect the layout of your page, the rendering of your page is blocked while downloading them. To render the page as quickly as possible its optimal to parse these resources quickly (by adding them to the `<head>` of the page) but also to contain as little as possible, only what's absolutely needed. This is the rationale for the rule of putting your CSS in the `<head>` of the page and your JavaScript at the bottom of the `<body>` as most JavaScript doesn't directly influence the layout of the page.

The *Page Speed Insights* rule you're referring to tries to optimize this even more. Instead of optimizing for the render speed of the entire page, it tries to optimize the render speed of the content above the page fold.

To do this the CSS in `<head>` should only contain those parts necessary to render the content above the fold (e.g. grid system, navbar and jumbotron; but not your form or footer). As that's likely only a little CSS they even suggest to add it in an inline `<style>` tag to have one http request less. The rest of the CSS is added later by having some JavaScript at the bottom of the `<body>` tag inject a `<link>` tag in the `<head>`.

But frankly I think it's something you shouldn't optimize for yet. I think there's more to gain by adding caching http headers to your static resources and to optimize the size of the images. Next to that your mobile site still has some JavaScript in the `<head>` and above the `<link>` tag.

Comment: I agree, optimize your images first, 60% reduction will give you 2 sec  less load time.